# Activity created twice in pending intent

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent, launchmode

I have a problem about activity created twice.

When the notification appears, the activity will appear because of the fullscreen intent. At this time, I press the home button and click the notification, and the activity is actually created again.

I tried to use singletop and it didn't work.
Log shows the same task, but the hash is different.

```
Log.e("Task", "task id: $taskId, hash: ${hashCode()}")
```

```
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        }, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "Alarm")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Content")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)
```

Comment: Why are you using NEW_TASK and CLEAR_TASK? This will definitely create a new `Activity`. If the app is already running, do you just want to bring it to the foreground? Or do you want to start a new `Activity`?

Comment: @DavidWasser Even if I remove the flag, it still cannot achieve the effect of singleTask

Comment: please explain what you want to happen. Your requirements are not clear. Also, have you set any launchMode in the manifest?

Comment: Also, please edit your question and post your manifest.